# Notice: Undefined index JavaScript Php

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo este codigo es una web para hacer reservar, donde quiero controlar la disponibilidad por franjas de horas, donde recupero las personas que introduce el usuario para comprovar que aquel dia a aquella hora no hay mas de 100 personas.

Cuando envió mediante el post las personas que ha introducido el usuario a traves del javascript a el fichero check_availability,  me sale el error de Undefined index dentro del php, donde  recuper-ho el valor de las personas en la linea 8 $persones = $_POST['persones'];.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {  
                $('#hora').on('blur', function(){

                    var data = document.getElementById("data");
                    var valor_data = data.value;

                    var persones = $(this).val();       
                    var personesString = 'persones='+persones;
                    
                    var hora = $(this).val();       
                    var horaString = 'hora='+hora;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "checks/check_availablity.php",
                        data: {data:valor_data, hora:hora, persones:persones},
                        success: function(valor_data, hora, persones) {
                            $('#result-hora').fadeIn(1000).html(valor_data,hora,persones);
                        }
                    });
                });              
            });    
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Navegador-->
        <?php include('nav.php');?>
        
        <div class="container-login">
            <div class="wrap-login" style="width: 1000px">
                <!--<form class="login-form validate-form" action="bd/reservar.php" method="post">-->
                <form class="login-form validate-form" id="reserves" action="" method="post">
                    <span class="login-form-title"><?php echo $Reserves_Titul; ?></span>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="wrap-input100 col-xs-6 espai-davant-text" data-validate = "Nom incorrecte">
                            <input class="input100" type="text" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="<?php echo $Reserves_form_Nom; ?>">
                            <span class="focus-efecto"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 col-xs-6 espai-davant-text" data-validate = "Email incorrecto">
                            <input class="input100" type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" placeholder="<?php echo $Reserves_form_Apellidos; ?>" >
                            <span class="focus-efecto"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100" style="width:100%" data-validate = "Email incorrecto">
                            <input class="input100" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="<?php echo $Reserves_form_Email; ?>">
                            <span class="focus-efecto"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 col-xs-6 espai-davant-text" data-validate="Telefon incorrecto">
                            <input class="input100" type="text" id="telefon" name="telefon" placeholder="<?php echo $Reserves_form_Telefon; ?>">
                            <span class="focus-efecto"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 col-xs-6 espai-davant-text" data-validate="Persones incorrecto">
                            <input class="input100" type="number" id="persones" name="persones" placeholder="<?php echo $Reserves_form_Persones; ?>">
                            <span class="focus-efecto"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100" style="width:100%" data-validate="Data incorrecto">
                            <input class="input100" type="date" id="data" name="data" placeholder="Fecha">
                            <span class="focus-efecto"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100" style="width:100%; margin-bottom: 10px" data-validate="Hora incorrecto">
                            <select name="hora" id="hora" class="input100">
                                <option disabled selected value=""><?php echo $Reserves_form_Hora; ?></option>
                                <option value="12:00">12:00</option>  
                                <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
                                <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                                <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
                                <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                                <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
                                <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
                                <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
                                <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
                                <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
                                <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="focus-efecto"></span>
                        </div>
                        <!--Mostrar disponibilitat-->
                        <div class="disponibilitat" id="result-hora"></div>
                        <div class="disponibilitat" id="result-persones"></div>
                        
                        <div class="container-login-form-btn">
                            <div class="wrap-login-form-btn">
                                <div class="login-form-bgbtn"></div>
                                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="login-form-btn">RESERVAR</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>                   
            </div>
        </div>
```

```html
          require('config.php');
    sleep(1);

    //Recuperem les dades del json
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $hora = $_POST['hora'];
    $persones = $_POST['persones'];
    
    //Maxim persones per a la mateix dia i hora
    $maxim_persones = 100;

    //Persones per a aquell dia a aquella hora
    $personesReservades = $connexion->query('SELECT SUM(persones) FROM reservas where data = \''.$data.'\' and hora = \''.$hora.'\'');

    //Contar numero de persones
    $contar_persones = mysqli_fetch_row($personesReservades);

    //Saber disponibilitat de llocs restants per a persones per aquell dia i hora
    $numero_persones = $maxim_persones - $contar_persones[0]; 

    //Comprobar el numero de persones a les reserves per al dia (+persones perque al realitzar el primer insert a la base de dades no hi ha cap persona i el contador retornada 0)
    $personesContades = $contar_persones[0] + $persones;
    
    if ($numero_persones == 0) {
        echo 'Esta tot reservat';
    }

    else if ($numero_persones <= 30) {
        echo 'Sols hi han '.$numero_persones.' llocs disponibles.';
        var_dump($_POST['persones']);
    }

    else {
    }
```

Comment: Es extraño que salga *Undefined index*, pues las key que mandas `{data:valor_data, hora:hora, persones:persones}` son las que luego usas en cada `$_POST`, no obstante, deberías verificar con `isset` o con ternario o con fusión de null. Lo que sí es raro es esto: `success: function(valor_data, hora, persones) {` porque tienes tres parámetros en el `success` y no, no funciona así. En el `success` recibes la respuesta del servidor, que es única, no es que por cada valor puesto en `data` luego `success` te responde por cada uno. En el servidor debes crear un json con cada dato para diferenciarlo.

Comment: Quizás el problema lo tienes porque haces esto en el javascript: `var persones = $(this).val();`  y luego esto: `var hora = $(this).val();`... ¿en que quedamos?  Son personas o son horas?  Dudo que tenga mucho que ver, pero entiendo que eso esta mal

Comment: Enronces como puedo enviar las horas y personas en el javascript

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios problemas en tu código:

1. No estás recogiendo correctamente los valores
2. Estás poniendo varios parámetros en el `success`

Intenta de este modo (ver comentarios en el mismo código):

### Cliente

```
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            $('#hora').on('blur', function(){
                /*
                   Unificaremos todo a estilo jQuery
                   y evitaremos valores que nunca usas
                   Observa que hora es un select
                   y la forma de recoger el valor es diferente
                */

                var data = $('#data').val();
                var persones = $('#persones').val();                           
                var hora = $('#hora').find(":selected").val();       

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "checks/check_availablity.php",
                    data: {data:data, hora:hora, persones:persones},
                    /*
                       OJO a esto: success recibe un sólo parámetro
                       que es la respuesta del servidor
                       En caso de necesitar un objeto estructurado,
                       debes crear un JSON en el servidor
                       pudiendo así acceder a cada propiedad del mismo por separado
                       Aquí el único dato nuevo sería el mensaje del servidor
                       Los otros datos ya los tienes a mano en el cliente
                    */
                    success: function(msg) {
                        var htmlText=`${data}\n${hora}\n${persones}\n\n${msg}`;                            
                        $('#result-hora').fadeIn(1000).html(htmlText);
                    }
                });
            });              
        });
```

---

### Servidor

```
require('config.php');
# ¿Para qué es esto?
sleep(1);

/*
   Recuperem les dades del json
   Usaremos fusión de null para verificar
   Si tienes PHP < 7 debes cambiarlo por ternarios
*/
$data = $_POST['data'] ?? NULL;
$hora = $_POST['hora'] ?? NULL;
$persones = $_POST['persones'] ?? NULL;

if($data && $hora && $persones) {
    //Maxim persones per a la mateix dia i hora
    $maxim_persones = 100;

    //Persones per a aquell dia a aquella hora
    $sql="SELECT SUM(persones) FROM reservas where data = '$data' and hora = '$hora'";
    if( $personesReservades = $connexion->query($sql) ) {

        //Contar numero de persones
        $contar_persones = $personesReservades->fetch_row();

        //Saber disponibilitat de llocs restants per a persones per aquell dia i hora
        $numero_persones = $maxim_persones - $contar_persones[0]; 

        /*
           Comprobar el numero de persones a les reserves per al dia 
          (+persones perque al realitzar el primer insert a la base de dades 
          no hi ha cap persona i el contador retornada 0)
          Pero, ¿para qué es la variable $personesContades?
        */
        $personesContades = $contar_persones[0] + $persones;

        if ($numero_persones == 0) {
            $outPut = 'Esta tot reservat';
        }else if ($numero_persones <= 30) {
            $outPut="Sols hi han $numero_persones llocs disponibles.";
       } else {
            $outPut='Ninguna se cumple ¿?';
       }
} else {
    $outPut="No se postearon datos, revisa el form";
}
echo $outPut;
exit;
```